# Take TCP stream and rebroadcast to UDP multicast?

Tags: networking, command-line, multicast, live-broadcast

How can I, in Windows and/or Linux, take data from a TCP stream and rebroadcast it on UDP to a specified multicast group?

The stream data will need to be chopped into chunks of 500 bytes or less. The TCP connection requires basic authentication.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking doesn't make sense.

The point of TCP is to create a connection.  That means data flows to and from both endpoints.

Multicast is one-to-many transmission with no expectation that the many will hold a stateful conversation back.  Multicast is primarily for things like media or notification delivery.

If what is coming across TCP is a media stream of some sort, you may look into some sort of transcoding utility that can convert to a multicastable form.  I'd bet `ffmpeg` could do this somehow, but don't know for sure.

Comment: It is for NTRIP data.